# snowflake select max date from date array

Tags: oracle, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Imagine I have a table with some field one of which is array off date.
as below

```
col1 col2 alldate                       Max_date
1    2    ["2021-02-12","2021-02-13"]   "2021-02-13"
2    3    ["2021-01-12","2021-02-13"]   "2021-02-13"
4    4    ["2021-01-12"]                "2021-01-12"
5    3    ["2021-01-11","2021-02-12"]   "2021-02-12"
6    7    ["2021-02-13"]                "2021-02-13"
```

I need to write a query such that to select only the one which has max date in there array. And there is a column which has max date as well.

Like the select statement should show

```
col1 col2 alldate                       Max_date
1    2    ["2021-02-12","2021-02-13"]   "2021-02-13"
2    3    ["2021-01-12","2021-02-13"]   "2021-02-13"
6    7    ["2021-02-13"]                "2021-02-13"
```

**The table is huge so a optimized query is needed.**
Till now I was thinking of

```
select col1, col2, maxdate
       from t1 where array_contains((select max(max_date) from t1)::variant,date));
```

But to me it seems running select statement per query is a bad idea.

Any Suggestion

Comment: Hi, what are the datatypes of the columns  all_date and max_date?

Comment: Hi Dan - you have 3 answers, and some you thanked personally. It would be cool if you could upvote and accept the ones that are useful to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want pure speed using lateral flatten is 10% faster than the array_contains approach over 500,000,000 records on a XS warehouse. You can copy paste below code straight into snowflake to test for yourself.

Why is the lateral flattern approach faster?
Well if you look at the query plans the optimiser filters at first step (immediately culling records) where as the array_contains waits until the 4th step before doing the same. The filter is the qualifier of the max(max_date) ...

Create Random Dataset:

```
create or replace table stack_overflow_68132958 as
SELECT
    seq4() col_1,
    UNIFORM (1, 500, random()) col_2,
    DATEADD(day, UNIFORM (-40, -0, random()), current_date()) random_date_1,
    DATEADD(day, UNIFORM (-40, -0, random()), current_date()) random_date_2,
    DATEADD(day, UNIFORM (-40, -0, random()), current_date()) random_date_3,
    ARRAY_CONSTRUCT(random_date_1, random_date_2, random_date_3) date_array,
    greatest(random_date_1, random_date_2, random_date_3) max_date,
    to_array(greatest(random_date_1, random_date_2, random_date_3)) max_date_array
FROM
TABLE (GENERATOR (ROWCOUNT => 500000000))  ;
```

Test Felipe/Mike approach -> 51secs

```
select 
 distinct 
 col_1
,col_2  
from 
  stack_overflow_68132958 
qualify 
 array_contains(max(max_date) over () :: variant, date_array);
```

Test Adrian approach -> 47 secs

```
select 
  distinct    
  col_1
, col_2 
from 
   stack_overflow_68132958
 , lateral flatten(input => date_array) g 
qualify 
    max(max_date) over () = g.value;
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks to Anna Flendrig for double checking the results and helping with solution.

Comment: You're more than welcome ... it's good to be thorough :-)

Answer (score 2):

I would likely use a CTE for this, like:

```
WITH x AS (
SELECT max(max_date) as max_max_date
FROM t1
)
select col1, col2, maxdate
from t1 
cross join x
where array_contains(x.max_max_date::variant,alldate);
```

I have not tested the syntax exactly and the data types might vary things a bit, but the concept here is that the CTE will be VERY fast and return a single record with a single value.  A MAX() function leverage metadata in Snowflake, so it won't even use a warehouse to get it.

That said, the Snowflake profiler is pretty smart, so your query might actually create the exact same query profile as this statement.  Test them both and see what the Profile looks like to see if it truly makes a difference.

Comment: For fun: I added a tested alternative (types got weird), and a solution with a single line in qualify

Answer (score 2):

To build on Mike's answer, we can do everything in the QUALIFY, without the need for a CTE:

```sql
with t1 as (
select 'a' col1, 'b' col2, '2020-01-01'::date maxdate, array_construct('2020-01-01'::date, '2018-01-01', '2017-01-01') alldate
)

select col1, col2, alldate, maxdate
from t1 
qualify array_contains((max(maxdate) over())::variant, alldate)
;
```

Note that you should be careful with types. Both of these are true:

```sql
select array_contains('2020-01-01'::date::string::variant, array_construct('2020-01-01', '2019-01-01'));
select array_contains('2020-01-01'::date::variant, array_construct('2020-01-01'::date, '2019-01-01'));
```

But this is false:

```sql
select array_contains('2020-01-01'::date::variant, array_construct('2020-01-01', '2019-01-01'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some great answers, which I only saw, after i wrote mine up.
If your data types, match, you should be good to go, copy paste direct into snowflake ... and this should work.

```
create or replace schema abc;
use schema abc;

create or replace table myarraytable(col1 number, col2 number, alldates variant, max_date timestamp_ltz);

insert into myarraytable
select 1,2,array_construct('2021-02-12'::timestamp_ltz,'2021-02-13'::timestamp_ltz), '2021-02-13'
union
select 2,3,array_construct('2021-01-12'::timestamp_ltz,'2021-02-13'::timestamp_ltz),'2021-02-13'
union
select 4,4,array_construct('2021-01-12'::timestamp_ltz)              ,  '2021-01-12'
union
select 5,3,array_construct('2021-01-11'::timestamp_ltz,'2021-02-12'::timestamp_ltz) ,  '2021-02-12'
union
select 6,7,array_construct('2021-02-13'::timestamp_ltz)              ,  '2021-02-13';


select * from myarraytable
order by 1 ;



WITH cte_max AS (
SELECT max(max_date) as max_date
FROM myarraytable
)

select myarraytable.* 
from myarraytable, cte_max  
where array_contains(cte_max.max_date::variant, alldates)
order by 1 ;
```